# A way to use Apache Thrift JS bindings with Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, thrift

I have a Thrift API (using the software at http://thrift.apache.org/).

I'd like to use Thrift JavaScript bindings ([example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/tutorial/js/tutorial.html)) in conjunction with Backbone.js, instead of REST.

Is this possible? Is there a conventional way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  Then entire "sync" layer is replaceable.  The Backbone.js documents have a bit of information about the [sync layer](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync).  Here is the default [(REST) implementation](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-162).

A simple example of replacing the sync layer can be found in the [backbone-localstorage extension](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html).

In your case, you just write the code for read, create, update and delete and Backbone takes care of the rest for you.

Also note that you can override the Sync layer globally or at an instance level (by using setting the "sync" property on the `Model` or `Collection` instance)

Comment: Brian, if you look at my example, you will notice that methods are being called directly against the Thrift client: client.calculate(1, work). URLs, which Backbone requires, are not used. So, I don't see how Backbone's "sync" layer can be used to interact with Thrift, since Thrift is RPC-like. Does Backbone support a non-RESTful approach? Can you explain?

Comment: The Backbone `Model` relies on you supplying operations for create, read, update, and delete.  As long as you can figure out how to map to those options, you can use the Backbone models.  You can just ignore the URL property on the model completely.  The "localstorage" example I linked to does that.  Instead, the model adds a localstorage property to the model.  You could do something similar, which would map the "get" action to your action... like `thriftProperties: new Thrift.Properties({action: calculate})`.  Your actual implementation would map to the way you want to use it.

Comment: I should add that if you can't map at least the `get` action, then a `Model` probably isn't appropriate.  You might just want to create a "Command" object that encapsulates your remote call for you and it returns your result... something like `var calculateCommand = new CalculateCommand();  calculateCommand.execute({success: successCallback})`.  Then you would just use the Backbone routers and views the same way, but with your custom command instead of a more formal `Backbone.Model` implementation.